# How to use BigQuery's union all with an inner join?

Tags: sql, join, inner-join, google-bigquery, reddit

I am attempting to join all `comment` tables (shards of comments each month) to a `posts` table. Is there a way for me to perform a union all before the inner join? Details on the union all operator can be found in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference). My query with only 1 of the comments table is as follows:

```
SELECT c.score, c.body, c.link_id, c.parent_id, p.created_utc, c.created_utc
FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01] AS c
INNER JOIN [fh-bigquery:reddit_posts.full_corpus_201512] AS p
ON c.parent_id = p.name
WHERE SUBSTR(c.parent_id, 1, 2) = 't3'
ORDER BY c.score DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mikhail Berlyant pointed out in his answer, modifying the query as such accomplished what I needed.

```
SELECT c.score, c.body, c.link_id, c.parent_id, p.created_utc, c.created_utc, (c.created_utc - p.created_utc) AS time_diff
FROM (
  SELECT * 
  FROM 
    [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_11],
    [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_12],
    [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01],
) AS c
INNER JOIN [fh-bigquery:reddit_posts.full_corpus_201512] AS p
ON c.parent_id = p.name
WHERE SUBSTR(c.parent_id, 1, 2) = 't3'
ORDER BY c.score DESC
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: suggestion: don't ever use `SELECT *` in BigQuery as you most likely will be over-billed. Use only fields you really need so you will be charged for only those fields vs for whole table as in using *

Comment: This particular `SELECT *` is okay. You will not be charged for fields that don't make it all the way through to the outer `SELECT`.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2016_01] AS c
```

with

```
FROM (
  SELECT score, body, link_id, parent_id, created_utc 
  FROM (TABLE_QUERY([fh-bigquery:reddit_comments], 
                    'REGEXP_MATCH(table_id, r"\d{4}_\d{2}")')) 
) AS c
```

Hope, this gives you idea
See more on [Table wildcard functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#tablewildcardfunctions) and [Regular expression functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#regularexpressionfunctions)